# Are there any interesting properties of the following symmetric circulate matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, circulant-matrices

Consider $a_0, \ldots, a_{k-1} \in \mathbb{R}$, consider matrix $\mathbf{A}$ as the following

$$\mathbf{A} =  \begin{bmatrix} a_{0} & a_{1} & \ldots & a_{k-1} \\
a_{1} & a_{0} & \ldots &a_{k-2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{k-1} & a_{k-2} & \ldots& a_{0} \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{A}^\top$$

Clearly, this matrix is symmetric, or hermitian, so it has a nice diagonal eigenvalue decomposition. Just curious what are the properties about this matrix.

Comment: one property is that it is a polynomial in the [shift matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix)